# How to create a separate file for aliases in .cshrc?

Tags: csh

I've tons of aliases in the *.cshrc* file. For example:

```
alias some_alias 'cd /some folder'
```

It's possible to have these aliases in a separate file ? This file is becoming huge.

Comment: As an aside, questions about configuring your interactive environment, as opposed to about writing scripts, might be a better fit for our sister site [unix.se] in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, none of the `csh` family of shells provides a mechanism for the `alias` subcommand to read aliases from a file, but of course you can use the `source` command in your `.cshrc` file to read additional input from an arbitrary file.  For example,

**.cshrc**

```
# ...
source ~/.aliases.csh
```

**.aliases.csh**

```
alias some_alias 'cd /some folder'
alias another_alias 'frob -x'
# ...
```

Answer (score -1):

To execute commands (like alias definitions) from another file, use the `source` command.

That is:

```
source .csh-aliases
```